# Is there an upper bound for the distance between the projections of the same point onto different closed convex sets?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, convex-optimization, projection

It is well-known that

> If $C$ is a closed and convex set in $\mathbb R^n$. Then
> $||\text{proj}_C(x) - \text{proj}_{C}(y)||\leq ||x-y||$ for all $x, y\in \mathbb R^n$.

Here $\text{proj}_C(x) =\arg\min_{z\in C} ||x-z||$ is the closest-point projection of $y$ onto closed convex set $C$.

I am wondering that

> If $A, B$ are closed and convex sets in $\mathbb R^n$. Then do we have a "tight" upper bound for $||\text{proj}_A(v) - \text{proj}_{B}(v)||$ where $v$ is some given point in $\mathbb R^n$.

My particular interested case is that $A\subset B$. Is there any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Not really, other than the diameter of the set.